# Executing .java in MS Window

Tags: windows, eclipse, macos, java

I am beginner in Java. Recently I used Eclipse in Mac to build a project which output below .class in bin folder of the workspace:

- Main.class
- MianWindow.class
- PaintPanel.class
  ...

I can exexute the JFrame appl'n when I double-click the Main.Class file in bin of the Mac PC.

However, when I copy all the stuff in bin folder to an Window PC and tried to run below command, it just failed to execute it:

command prompt used:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin>java c:\temp\bin\Main.class
```

Error msg:

```
Exeception in thread "main" java.land.NoClassDefFindError: c:\temp\bin\Main/class ...     

Could not find the main class...Program will exit.
```

Any step(s) I missed when executing the program?

One more question about Java Applet... if I was to allow a new client's PC to run a Java Applet, So everytime when there is a new client, I have to compile the java project on client's PC before they can run the Applet?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to specify the extension of the Java application i.e remove `.class`.

Try this: `java c:\temp\bin\Main`

Also if you have packaged your java file then it would have to be first in the package and then run.
Say for exampleif you have declared your class as

```
package com.my.app;

public class Main{
}
```

then you will have to move class file to `com/my/app` folder and then run as

```
java c:\temp\bin\com.my.app.Main
```

Answer (score 0):

`Java` command does not include current directory in `classpath` by default. Follow below steps

1. Open command prompt
2. Go to directory where all classes are compiled
3. Execute java command like `java -cp . Main`

   I can see there are three classes(`Main.class` `MianWindow.class` `PaintPanel.class`) in directory you have to set that directory to `classpath`

Comment: ok. Thanks man. I succeed running it with C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin>java -classpath c:\temp\bin Main .... but can I set "." as classpath?

Comment: . means current directory in your case you are already setting classpath directory as 'c:\temp\bin'. and you are executing java command from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin so additional setting is not required. Java command will try to find Main class in the dırectory you set as 'c:\temp\bin' hence it will be valid and scuccess.

Comment: Another way you can do it as c:\temp\bin> java -classpath . Main